# Is there a sensible notion of abstract constructible space?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

In the past by the term "variety" people understood a subset of projective space locally closed for the Zariski topology. Now we have a more natural notion of abstract algebraic variety, i.e. a scheme that is so and so, and we can conceive non quasi-projective varieties.

Now we have the concept of constructible subset of a variety (or of a scheme), i.e. a finite union of locally closed subsets (subschemes).
We know that the image of a morphism of varieties may fail to be a subvariety of the target, nevertheless it's always a constructible subset thereof.

Is there a reasonable notion of "abstract constructible space"? And would it be of any utility in algebraic geometry?

Edit:
A side question. If we have a map $f:X\to Y$ of -say- varieties, we can put a closed subscheme structure on the (Zariski) closure $Z$ of $f(X)$, as described in Hartshorne's book. 
On the other hand we can consider the ringed space (that will not be, in genberal, a scheme) $W$ which is the quotient of $X$ by the equivalence relation induced by $f$. Will there be any relation between $Z$ and $W$?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructible_sheaf  Presumably then a constructible geometric space is a ringed space where the structure sheaf satisfies this property.  

Comment: Taking quotients by equivalence relations is not even really the right idea for locally ringed spaces.  Rather, the way to extend taking quotients is to consider schemes as sheaves on the opposite category of commutative rings with the étale topology (functors of points).  When we take quotients in this category by étale equivalence relations, we end up with algebraic spaces, which don't really have an interpretation as locally ringed spaces.  If we want to take more quotients but still end up outside of our category, this is when we generalize further to stacks.

Comment: @fpqc: My guess is that underlying your suggestion for a definition is the belief that constructible subsets of varieties have the property you suggest. But given a constructible subset of a variety how do you propose to put a ringed space structure on it so that the structure sheaf becomes a constructible sheaf?

Comment: My first comment was really just a guess, because I can't find his definition of a constructible scheme (yes, I looked for about 15 minutes).  Every definition I found had this requirement about a twisted locally constant sheaf.  My second comment is true though.

Comment: @fpqc: as far as I know there is no such thing as a constructible scheme, so it doesn't surprise me that you couldn't find a definition.

Comment: @fpqc: Actually, *there exists* a precise definition of "quotient ringed space", at least if the structure sheaf is a subsheaf of the (sheaf of rings of) set-theoretical functions with values in a given field. I came across this defn. while attending an introductory course of a.g. (in which alg. varieties, using an approach "à la Serre", were considered a subcategory of these ringed spaces).



Comment: (continued) Uhm, in fact one should add some topological requirements on the subsheaf of set-theoretical funcions I mentioned above. In that context, as far as I remember, you do have a well defined notion of quotient (which of course in general will fail to be a variety), and will have even the definition of an induced structure of the same kind on any subset.

Comment: @fpqc again: I'm aware of the "schemes-->algebraic spaces-->DM stacks---> Artin stacks" generalizations. But here it seems to me that we're generalizing (if possible) in another direction: about things that do not look like Spec(A) even zariski-, étale-, etc- locally. 

Comment: By the way, I don't know if those twisted locally constant sheaves (local systems?) are the right candidates to be a structure sheaf for some geometrical object. Not if I want "regular functions" to correspond to morphism to the "usual" $\mathbb{A}^{1}$, I'd guess.

Comment: No, the point is that taking the quotient in a different category gives you a different result.  For example, the quotient of a manifold by a group action is very often degenerate, but when you take the sheaf quotient á la Mumford's geometric invariant theory, you end up with a much nicer space.  Remember, quotients (being coequalizers) depend on the ambient category.  

Comment: A scheme is not naturally a locally ringed space (although every scheme has a representation as one).  Rather, in its most basic form, it is a sheaf of sets on the category of affine schemes. 